# Colorbar tick values not displayed python

Tags: python

i have plotted a figure using matshow and want to display the legend. However i only want the values between 18 and 28 to be displayed on the legend.

I have used the command :

```
colorbar(values=arange(18,28)).
```

I have exactly what i want on the colorbar in terms of color but the tick values are not displayed.

I tried with :

```
colorbar(ticks=arange(18,28))
```

and also

```
colorbar(ticks=arange(18,28),values=arange(18,28))
```

but it did not work.
How can i solve it ?
Thanks.

Comment: This should help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704353/correcting-matplotlib-colorbar-ticks

Comment: Thanks but i don't think this one works for my case. My ticks values don't appear at all. It is not a problem of number of color and number of ticks matching on the legend. I think my main problem is that the values displayed on the figure and the ones i want to show on the legend don't match.

Comment: Actually using boundaries instead of values solves the problem. Thanks anyway