# Any way to change color bar (cbar) in seaborn to a legend (for a binary heatmap)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm using the heatmap in seaborn (sns.heatmap) to show a matrix of binary values true/false. It works just fine but the color bar as expected is showing a range of values from 0-1 (when in reality there are only two colors).

Is there any way to change this to a legend showing the true/false colors? I couldn't find anything in the documentation

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[False,True,False,True,True,True],
                   'b':[False,False,False,False,True,False],
                   'c':[False,True,True,False,True,True],
                   'd':[False,True,False,True,True,True],
                   'e':[False,True,True,False,False,True],
                   'f':[False,True,False,False,True,True]})


# Set up the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(13, 13))

# Generate a custom diverging colormap
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(300, 180, as_cmap=True)

# Draw the heatmap with the mask and correct aspect ratio
_ = sns.heatmap(df, cmap=cmap, center=0, square=True, linewidths=.5, cbar_kws={"shrink": .5})
```

Comment: A minimal working code with some sample data would help us trying things

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a solution using some random data (working on this before you included data in your post). The solution was adapted to work for your problem from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836154/discrete-legend-in-seaborn-heatmap-plot) link.

```
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
import numpy as np
import random
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()

# Generate data
uniform_data = np.array([random.randint(0, 1) for _ in range(120)]).reshape((10, 12))

# Define colors
colors = ((1.0, 1.0, 0.0), (1, 0.0, 1.0))
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('Custom', colors, len(colors))

ax = sns.heatmap(uniform_data, cmap=cmap)

# Set the colorbar labels
colorbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
colorbar.set_ticks([0.25,0.75])
colorbar.set_ticklabels(['0', '1'])
```

**Output**

[image]

**Applying on your problem:**

```
# Set up the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))

colors = ["gray", "lightgray"] 
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('Custom', colors, len(colors))


# Draw the heatmap with the mask and correct aspect ratio
_ = sns.heatmap(df, cmap=cmap,square=True,  linewidths=.5, cbar_kws={"shrink": .5})

# Set the colorbar labels
colorbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
colorbar.set_ticks([0.25,0.75])
colorbar.set_ticklabels(['0', '1'])
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I ran this on the example and i'm getting no difference in colors (and a non-binary scale), can you show how it would work on the example code?

Comment: I had to remove `center = 0` from your heatmap to make it work. I don't see any change in the x or y axis labels if I include `center=0` or not.

Comment: The docs say that **The value at which to center the colormap when plotting divergant data**. Since you do not have any divergent data, I don't think you need it.

Comment: Works perfectly now. Thanks for the help! Don't think i would have ever thought of using LinearSegmentedColormap