# create custom cmap for seaborn heatmap

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

this is a great heatmap: http://graphics.wsj.com/infectious-diseases-and-vaccines/
I'm trying to do something similar in Seaborn, and wondered if I could take a custom color palette like turn it into a cmap, and then use center in order to skew it?

```
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

mypalette = ['#e8f0ff', '#51abff', '#12b74c', '#fffb16', '#ffc044', '#ff9400', '#ff6a00', '#c13300', '#b20c0c']
sns.palplot(sns.color_palette(mypalette))
```

The closest I can get is something like

```
plt.figure('hmap')
flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
ax = sns.heatmap(flights, cmap = mypalette, center = 350)
```

of course, this palette lacks a gradient. Apologies for the dataset, I realise it isn't skewed, but seemed like a simple one to use.

Answer (score 3):

Use Listed colors or Linear Segmented Colormap from Matplotlib,  eg. like in this question ([Discrete legend in seaborn heatmap plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836154/discrete-legend-in-seaborn-heatmap-plot/56678411)):

```
myColors = ((0.8, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 1.0), (0.0, 0.0, 0.8, 1.0))

cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('Custom', myColors, len(myColors))
```

You can specify your colours using RGB or also hex format. However, seaborn provides many predefined palettes, see https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/color_palettes.html.