# How does cmap work in seaborn and how to change binning?

Tags: python, r, seaborn, heatmap

The inspiration for this question comes from breaks in [pheatmap in R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pheatmap/versions/1.0.12/topics/pheatmap). The question is if I can define how "rough", how continuous/discrete my colouring and binning is in seaborn's heatmap. I have found a way how to do it using cmap and the number of colours used (eg. [Discrete legend in seaborn heatmap plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836154/discrete-legend-in-seaborn-heatmap-plot/56678411)). However, I have no idea how the assignment to those colour groups is done.

---

So the **questions are**, **how are the data binned** if I use cmap and force seaborn to use only a discrete set of colours=bins? How can I **set it manually**? Eg. in the case of R, I can set the breaks to be from 0 to 800 by step of 100 and pass it to the "breaks" argument.

> breaksList = seq(0, 800, by = 100)

It is quite simple to use cmap and number of colours if my scale is linear but if I would like to have my bins=colorbar logarithmic or just **not equally spaced**, how would I do that?

---

To give a concrete example, let me present the example of flights data set. On the left is the original default plot, on the right, I choose 5 colours to have 5 bins. So how are defined the edges of those bins? Can I reset them so that I have eg. bins 0-200, 200-300, 300-400, 400-600, above 600?
(I'm intentionally using unequal bins to show what I mean.)

```
# choose 5 colours to create 5 bins
cmap = sns.color_palette('rocket', n_colors=5)

# run this without the cmap argument to get the first image
flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")
ax = sns.heatmap(flights, cmap = cmap)
```

[image: Original heatmap WITHOUT using cmap.]
[image: Heatmap with 5 discrete sections created using cmap and choosing 5 colours.]

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there is a bug in seaborn that prevents the below idea from working correctly, so falling back to pure matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import seaborn as sns
# choose 5 colours to create 5 bins
colors = sns.color_palette('rocket', 5)
levels = [0, 200, 300, 400, 600]
cmap, norm = matplotlib.colors.from_levels_and_colors(levels, colors, extend="max")

flights = sns.load_dataset("flights")
flights = flights.pivot("month", "year", "passengers")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(flights.values, cmap = cmap, norm=norm)
ax.set(xticks=range(flights.shape[1]), yticks=range(flights.shape[0]),
       xticklabels=flights.columns, yticklabels=flights.index)
ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=90)
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, spacing="propotional")

plt.show()
```

[image]