# Seaborn Heatmap with only two colors: Col1 for values > x, Col2 for values < x

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I have a n x n pandas dataframe with values from 0.94 - 1.

I'm plotting a heatmap with seaborn as follows:

`heatmap = sb.heatmap(data.corr(), vmin=0.994, vmax=1, annot=True, cmap='BrBG', fmt=".4f")`

I want every field with a value over a certain x (say 0.997) to be red, and everything below blue. So only two colors. How do I do that?

Can't seem to find any easy answer on this or any other forum.

Comment: `sb.heatmap(data.corr() > threshold)` ?

Comment: I think a solution like the answer to this question might work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836154/discrete-legend-in-seaborn-heatmap-plot

Comment: `sns.heatmap(data.corr() > threshold, annot=data.corr(), fmt=".4f", cbar=False, cmap='bwr')`